# Importing water quality data from USGS URL

Tags: r, url, import

I saw similar questions but either it is not for R or somewhat different. I am trying to download water quality data from USGS websites for multiple stations similar to the following link: [USGS Data](http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nj/nwis/uv?cb_00010=on&format=rdb&site_no=01387940&period=&begin_date=2014-05-14&end_date=2014-05-21)

All I am trying to do is to download data from URLs similar to the above and put to data in a data frame in a usable format. i understand that some urls may not have data and need an errorcheck for that.

some answers have already been provided to this question an appreciate it.

Comment: So what are you trying to get? Instantaneous data? daily data?  the data from the link? [This link](http://waterdata.usgs.gov/usa/nwis/rt) says it has real-time data.

Comment: Don't understand the negative marking. All I am trying to do is download data from the URL and get the data in a data frame/matrix.

Comment: jhoward has answered my question.

Comment: Just and fyi, the down-vote did not come from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want exactly, but if the question is how to get the content from this url into a data frame, then:

```
url <- "http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nj/nwis/uv?cb_00010=on&format=rdb&site_no=01387940&period=&begin_date=2014-05-14&end_date=2014-05-21"
df  <- read.csv(url,header=T,sep="\t",skip=24)
```

will work. The data is tab-delimited, so we specify `sep="\t"`. The first 24 lines are comments, so we skip these. You may have to delete the first row, as it contains information that does not appear to be in the same format as the other rows. To get real-time data, remove the name-value pair: `end_date=2014-05-21` from the url query string.

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment.

This is a somewhat long-winded but cleaner approach to retrieving data from a site. Note that there is no error checking. This assumes that the site you provide will in fact have data (not all sites do).

```
get.waterdata <- function(site) {
  host  <- "http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nj/nwis/uv"
  query <- "cb_00010=on&format=rdb&period=&begin_date=2014-05-14&end_date=2014-05-21"
  query <- paste(query,paste("site_no",site,sep="="),sep="&")
  url   <- paste(host,query,sep="?")
  df <- read.csv(url,header=T,sep="\t",skip=24)
  return(df)
}

df <- get.waterdata("01387950")
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The number "013879408" in the URL is the station number. Can I use a variable, say "station" in the URL and choose the value of the station from a vector?

Comment: Hi.  There is also a UGSG package for R called [Data Retreival](https://github.com/USGS-R/dataRetrieval), designed specifically for obtaining water quality data.  As far as the URLs are concerned, there are URL generating forms for these requests located at http://waterservices.usgs.gov/.  You cannot use "station" as a variable in the URL, the syntax is very specific.  I usually request RDB format, which is just a tab delimited text file.  [Here](http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/?tab_delimited_format_info) is an explanation of RDB file format.